# Magento 2 - run function if order is marked complete?

Tags: magento2, orders, extensions, api

I need to submit the following information to a third-party. I've started working on a PHP file (outside of Magento 2) to get the data from the Magento database but I'm having issues getting custom attribute text at the moment and I understand using the API is probably the way to go but I can't seem to get it working.

How can I create a function that runs as soon as I mark an order as complete? This would enable me to send the ID of the order that is marked complete to the third-party.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event `sales_order_save_after`, which is fired just after order is saved. Create an observer for this event and based on order status execute your logic (see `\Magento\Reward\Observer\OrderCompleted::execute` as an example).

Comment: It'll be my first time creating a Magento 2 extension, but I'll give it a go!